# Visual Studio Python start pip.exe, debug setup.py

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, pip

I recently started using Python on Visual Studio 2019, and I need to test and enhance code developed by other people. Now, I need to write a few extra lines in `setup.py`, and need to debug to make sure that I understand the code where I am making the changes.

Typically, the user would run `pip install` with a number of parameters, and then pip will call setup and pass it some information. I want to know what information pip passes to setup and how. Once I know that, I can set `setup.py` as a startup file and pass the parameters via project / properties / Debug / Script arguments.

That means that I want to start `pip.exe`, pass it parameters, and then debug `setup.py`. I tried adding `pip.exe` to the project, but don't see any way to start it. If I start pip in a command prompt, `setup.py` runs, but the debugger is not invoked and doesn't hit the breakpoints.

I read about "attach to process", but I don't see any way to attach the debugger to the `python.exe` process before the process has been started.

Comment: I found a workaround for this. At the beginning of setup.main, I added the lines
    print('Entering setup.py');
    print(len(sys.argv));
    print(str(sys.argv));
Then I use the result of this as script argument and start setup.py directly in the debugger. About 30 years ago, I wrote some C code on Unix without a debugger, and called this method "writeln debugging".
There must be a better way to do it.